# Excel Filter Function + Data Validation

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: TABLE1]

Im looking to create a data validation list based on multiple filters and the new filter function seems like a potentially perfect fit

Where h22 `=FILTER(B22:D25,(C22:C25=F22)*(D22:D25=G22),"")`

and h23 `=INDEX(FILTER(B22:D25,(C22:C25=F22)*(D22:D25=G22),""),,1)`

So im looking to list all values which match the given id1 and id2 in f22 and g22 respectively

I've managed to use the index function to return the filter as only the first column however to use in a data validation i require it as a delimited list

All help very appreciated!

Final application:

[image]

the connector cell currently has the formula used to return the connector type used on the sensor selected from the dropdown

the cable cell currently has the formula used to return the number of pins used on the sensor selected from the dropdown

the idea would be to filter all cables with the given connector type and number of pins and show the results in a data validation list under the cable column

Comment: so you want the list so you can copy paste into the datavalidation, because you cannot use Filter in datavalidation.  You will need to create the list in cells then refer to the range.  And BTW INDEX is not needed: `=FILTER(B22:B25,(C22:C25=F22)*(D22:D25=G22),"")` You can limit the return value to only the first column.

Answer (score 5):

First you do not need INDEX,  Filter allows you to limit the output to what you want:

```
=FILTER(B22:B25,(C22:C25=F22)*(D22:D25=G22),"")
```

To use this with DataValidation one will need to use a helper range.

In an empty column put the formula above.  Then using DataValidation refer to the spilled range by using the suffix `#` on the cell reference:

[image]

[image]

Now it will grow or shrink with the data.

[image]

DataValidation requires an actual typed comma delimited string(not a formula that returns one) or a range.  The `=$H$22#` satisfies the second one.

Comment: ..............Great answer! ....................

Comment: A good workaround! I tried to simplify the problem since it will have the data validation within a table and id1 and id2 passed from vlookup results. Unfortuantly having a spare column specifically for the filter results wouldnt be feasable since it would have the data validation repeated down a column with no fixed limits. The solution would work perfectly for something smaller just not this one unfortuantly :(